# Return collection of pairs of objects that satisfy a condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a single list of objects.  These objects have a "match" function that compares a passed object of the same type with themselves and returns true if a condition is met.  If this condition is true, I want the objects to be able to manipulate each other.  I want to get a collection of all pairs of objects stored in my list where objectA.match(objectB) == true.  Or, better yet, execute a method on these pairs such that objectA calls a method with objectB as its parameter if objectA.match(objectB) == true.  How would I use LINQ to accomplish this?  This sounds like it could be a self-join but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you paste your code so we can help you improve what already exists.

Comment: There's not much to paste, it's just a dynamically populated List of custom objects.  I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: It is not clear do you have one collection with type which contain two objects? or you have two collections one of `objectA`, another of `objectB`.

Comment: One collection of objects of the same type (but possibly different subtypes) see edit

Answer (score 1):

This will search for all matches in listB for each element in listA, and subsequently execute the method **MethodToManipulate** for each listA element's matches while passing them as parameter.

```
listA.ForEach(a => {
            var matches = listB.Where(b => b.Match(a));
            foreach (var m in matches) a.MethodToManipulate(m); 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I guess it should look this:

```
var listA = GetListA();
var listB = GetListB();

var max =  listA.Where(x=>listB.Any(s=>s.Match(x)).ToList().Count();

//mathPairList is 2 dimensions Array which holds [listAitem, listBitem]
Object[,] matchPairList= new Object[max, 2];
int row = 0;

foreach(var listAitem in listA)
{
  var listBitem= listB.Where(s=>s.Match(listAitem)).FirstOrDefault().;
  if (match != null)
  {
      matchPairList[row,0] = listAitem;
      matchPairList[row,1] = listBitem; 
      row++;
  }
}
```

Should give same results depending on your lists of course.

```
s.Match()  <= should be your implementation
```

Comment: Will this give me the pairs of objects that pass the match?  Or will it just give me a list of objects that passed a match with some other object?

Comment: this will give you a list of objects that satisfy the match method between 2 lists (listA, listB),
imagine [SQL inner join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/img_innerjoin.gif)

Comment: But I want a list of pairs of matching objects.

Comment: @GameKyuubi please check the updated answer, this should be what you need.